# Return result after for loop finishes adding to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to return an array after a `forEach` loop has finished adding items to it. I have tried several methods but they all either return an empty array or an unresolved promise.

### My Code

```
class handleFiles {
  constructor() {
    this.promiseFiles = [];
    this.promiseFolders = [];
  }
  async returnFilesAndFolders() {
    fs.readdir("uploads", (err, files) => {
      files.forEach((file) => {
        if (fs.statSync(path.resolve(`uploads/${file}`)).isFile()) {
          this.promiseFiles.push(file);
        } else if (fs.statSync(path.resolve(`uploads/${file}`)).isDirectory()) {
          this.promiseFolders.push(file);
        } else {
        }
      });
    });
    let combined = {
      sendFiles: Promise.all(this.promiseFiles),
      sendFolders: Promise.all(this.promiseFolders),
    };
    return combined;
  }
}
```

**Calling the class**

```
app.get("/:dir?", (req, res) => {
  let dir = req.params.dir;
  console.log(dir);
  let fileHandler = new handleFiles();

  fileHandler.returnFilesAndFolders().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    res.render("index", {
      data: data,
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Readdir returns a promise so you can `await fs.readdir...`

Comment: @Charles Bamford I'm trying to separate it into files and folders.

Comment: `returnFilesAndFolders()` returns an array with two promises. `Array` does not have a `then` method.

Comment: `let combined = {` happens before your arrays have been populated. it needs to happen after. promisify the readdir and await it or return the promise.

Comment: @ Kevin B How do I make it happen after?

Comment: promisify the readdir and await it or return it

Comment: @Kevin B Could you add an answer? I'm afraid I only know this basic amount of async coding.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323

Comment: @Kevin B The thing is I've gone through several such answers, and tried various suggested approaches, but I can't seem to fix the issue. After you pointed out that the combined is being called before my arrays are populated, I seem to understand why its returning as empty but I dont know how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original implementation has several timing problems.  Your `.forEach()` loop does not wait for any of the async operations inside it to complete so you end up calling `Promise.all()` before the arrays are filled.  I would suggest using the `fs` operations that have built-in promise support and also use the `withFileTypes` option with `fs.promises.readdir()`:

```
class handleFiles {
  constructor() {
    this.promiseFiles = [];
    this.promiseFolders = [];
  }
  async getFilesAndFolders() {
      let files = await fs.promises.readdir("uploads", {withFileTypes: true});
      for (let file of files) {
          if (file.isFile()) {
              this.promiseFiles.push(file.name);
          } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
              this.promiseFolders.push(file.name);
          }
      }
      return {
          sendFiles: this.promiseFiles,
          sendFolders: this.promiseFolders
      }
  }
}
```

Note: this implementation is a bit odd in that it is BOTH filling `this.promiseFiles` and `this.promiseFolders` and is returning a promise that resolves to an object containing that data.  I'd really suggest you do one or the other.  Also, because of this side-effect programming of adding to `this.promiseFiles` and `this.promiseFolders`, if you call `getFilesAndFolders()` more than once, it will create duplicates.

Perhaps you don't need this data in your instance data at all and the method can just return a promise that resolves to the object as so:

```
class handleFiles {
  constructor() {
  }
  async fillFilesAndFolders() {
      const sendFiles = [], sendFolders = [];
      let files = await fs.promises.readdir("uploads", {withFileTypes: true});
      for (let file of files) {
          if (file.isFile()) {
              sendFiles.push(file.name);
          } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
              sendFolders.push(file.name);
          }
      }
      return {
          sendFiles,
          sendFolders
      };
  }
}
```

But, now this is just a static method that doesn't really have anything to do with the class so perhaps it could just be a stand-alone function or a static method.

Step-by-step Description in the 2nd solution:

1. Declare local variables `promiseFolders` and `promiseFiles`.
2. Call `await fs.promises.readdir()` so we can use the promise interface for `readdir`.
3. Pass the `withFileTypes` option so we get access to `isFile()` and `isDirectory()` without making an additional call for every file.
4. Iterate through the list of `files` and populate the desired `promiseFiles` or `promiseFolders` array with the file's name.
5. Build the returned data structure and return it (which will be the resolved value of the promise returned from the parent `async` function.

Comment: Thank you so much, your second solution was my initial requirement (which I converted into a function). Do u mind explaining the sequence of whats happening

Comment: @rishi - I added a step-by-step description.

Comment: Thank you so much, however I still dont understand why your `return` runs after the `for loop` while in my code didn't.

Comment: @rishi -  You have asynchronous operations inside your `.forEach()` loop.  That loop does not pause for those asynchronous operations - it just launches them all in parallel, the loop finishes and then the asynchronous operations finish some time later.  I'm using `await` with a single asynchronous operation that returns a promise and I have no asynchronous operations inside the loop.

Comment: @rishi - You can have asynchronous operations inside a loop, but if you want the loop to wait for them, you must use a plain `for` or `while` loop and you must use `await` with asynchronous operations that return promises.  `.forEach()` is not promise-aware so it cannot be used to sequence promises.  In fact, I'd argue, `.forEach()` should basically be deprecated now because a `for` loop gives you so much more control and we have block scope and this is all  even more true with asynchronous operations.  Also a `for` loop can be more optimized by the interpreter too.

Answer (score -2):

```
async returnFilesAndFolders() {
  // Return the fs.readdir promise.
  return fs.readdir("uploads").then((files) => {

    // Collect the files into files and folders.
    return files.reduce((acc, file) => {
      // Get the status of the file.
      const stat = fs.statSync(path.resolve(`uploads/${file}`));

      if (stat.isFile()) {
        acc.sendFiles.push(file);
      }
      elseif (stat.isDirectory()) {
        acc.sendFolders.push(file);
      }

      return acc;
    }, {sendFiles: [], sendFolders: []})
  });
}
```

`file` is just a string, not a promise, so it doesn't need to be resolved. `fs.readdir` returns a promise, so it can be used with `.then`. The intermediary promiseFiles and promiseFolders will be empty when the process exits, but they aren't needed because `file` is not a promise.

Comment: be careful not to mix the callback version of readdir with the promise version https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promise_example

Comment: @Charles Bamford This seems to return undefined?

Comment: @Kevin B WOuld you know why this code is returning undefined?

Comment: Yes, `fs.readdir("uploads", (err, files) => {` doesn't return anything. see the docs above

Comment: This does not return anything from the `returnFilesAndFolders()` function.  It only returns something from the `fs.readdir()` callback which goes nowhere (back into the bowels of the `fs` module where it is ignored).

Comment: Mb. I think i fixed it.